# how to create a variable script in document.write in html tag?

Tags: javascript, html

the code:

```
<script>var posterimage=/images/videos/intro/iamge01.png;</script>
<script>document.write('<video controls="controls" height="300" id="video-playlist" poster="VARIABLE" preload="none" src="video.mp4" width="300"></video>');</script>
```

the video player work in html but the poster image not appear.

Comment: Try putting quotes around the value of posterimage.  Make sure that the image is accessable directlry (http://yourdomain.com/images/videos/intro/iamge01.png,  Check the spelling of the file name (iamge01?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use string [concatenation](http://2ality.com/2011/10/string-concatenation.html) to do this:

```
var posterimage= '/images/videos/intro/iamge01.png';
document.write('<video controls="controls" height="300" id="video-playlist" poster="' + posterimage +'" preload="none" src="video.mp4" width="300"></video>');
```

You could also use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to do this:

```
var posterimage= '/images/videos/intro/iamge01.png';
document.write(`<video controls="controls" height="300" id="video-playlist" poster="${posterimage}" preload="none" src="video.mp4" width="300"></video>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

- First, you don't need each script instruction to be in its own
  `script` tag.
- Second, you shouldn't be using `document.write()` unless you are
  creating new content in a new `window`. Instead, just populate a
  pre-existing element.
- Third, literal strings must be quoted.
- Finally, you just need to concatenate the variable reference into
  your string:

  ```
  <script>
    // String literals must be quoted
    var posterimage = "/images/videos/intro/iamge01.png";

    // You should get a reference to an empty container element
    // that you want the video to go into and then just set the 
    // content of that element:
    elementReference.innerHTML(`<video controls="controls" height="300" 
                                       id="video-playlist" poster="` + 
                                       posterimage + `" preload="none" 
                                       src="video.mp4" width="300"></video>`);
  </script>
  ```